# The meaning of a notation of conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory

The following statement is one aspect of the definition of the Markov family.  I didn't understand the meaning of conditioning on $X_s = y$, and in what sense can we view the LHS as a map of $y$. Thank you!

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^d, s,t \ge 0,$ and $\Gamma \in \mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$,
$$
\mathbb{P}^x \left[ X_{t+s} \in \Gamma \left| X_s = y \right. \right]
 = \mathbb{P}^y \left[ X_t \in \Gamma \right],
$$
$\mathbb{P}^x X_s^{-1}$-a.e. $y$.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try to find a reference but I think the following guess makes sense.

$\mathbb{P}^x \left[ X_{t+s} \in \Gamma \left| X_s = y \right. \right]$ is the Radon–Nikodym derivative of the two measures, on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\mathbb{P}^x \left[ \{X_{t+s} \in \Gamma \} \cap \{ X_s\in (\cdot) \} \right] \ll \mathbb{P}^xX_s^{-1}$.